# Django Rest Framework - search_fields - DatabaseError at /chapters/ No exception message supplied

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Based on the documentation of DRF search_fields, i have implemented search filter in one of my APIs with Foreign key field. So while searching i am facing this error. Can you guys please help me out to get this issue resolved?

This is my Parent Model

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    short_code = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=None)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=None)
    status = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None)
```

this is my child model

```
class ChapterTopicTag(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And this is my viewset

```
class ChapterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ChapterSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['status']
    search_fields = ('name', 'description', 'chpatertopic__name',)
```

Whenever i am calling url like
http://localhost:8000/parent/?search=childname

It throws me this error which is attached in screenshot[image: Error Screenshot one]
[image: Error Screenshot 2][image: Error Screenshot 3][image: Error Screenshot Four][image: Error Screenshot 5][image: Error Screenshot 6][image: Error Screenshot 7][image: Error Screenshot 8][image: Error Screenshot 9]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your search parameter on ulr will be the one of your search_fields declared on your View.

so...
Instead of *http://localhost:8000/parent/?search=childname*

You need to pass something like *http://localhost:8000/parent/?name=example_name*

The rule is *?search_field=search_value*

After that your have a typo in one of yours fields. **'chpatertopic__name'**
And your a trying to do a [Reverse relation](https://allwin-raju-12.medium.com/reverse-relationship-in-django-f016d34e2c68) on your models.

For now I recommend put a related_name attribute on your Child Model

Change this:

```py
class ChapterTopicTag(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    #parent_id = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='topic')
```

And than you have a new search field **'topic__chapter_name'**.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. Tried with the same, but it is not at all searching. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZgsPThNgqoFWaRE7cgW7pVTBBDejcBLw/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e0ep-4SSg07nBaSKxFj9Myyc-CdM0lGe/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXOep7roBZrBH3oXDzqBQoAlLEsh82lL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello Bala, Can you explain in more details what fields you expect to search with ?

Comment: Chapter.objects.filter(chaptertopictag__name__icontains='cddd'). This is what i want to include it in the search_fields of chapterviewset sir. As you have mentioned i want to search the chapters which contains tags. so search_fields = ('name', 'description', 'chaptertopictag__name') - As you mentioned it is Reverse relationship only.